# Lightning Experience: Open a Visualforce page from a record detail page

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

Seemingly simple...  In Classic I can add a button to the top of a record detail page that I can define a Visualforce page I want to open, that has the sObject set as the standard controller.  In Lightning Experience, how do I achieve this?  I want a button that I can click that will open a custom VF page and have the Id passed as a param in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So figured this out, and it's a bit clunky if you ask me.

1. Create a VF page that uses the sObject as the StandardController
2. Create an Action on the sObject that opens the page you just created
3. In the controller, create a method that returns a PageReference to the VF page you actually want to go to, and pass add any parameters there.
4. On the VF page, set the method you created as the Action property in the  element, like Action={!goToPage}

The downside, you get this big empty modal that pops up for a second before actually redirecting you.  The modal has action buttons at the bottom as well... which you can't get rid of.